# how to stop the fs.read() function in node.js?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I need to stop the fs.read () function when it does not read any character, any way? I just want to it when not read any characters because it is in a loop that takes and I want it fast.

Comment: Could you share code and then explain what you want to do.